# Not able replace word in text file using powershell commands on remote machine using python pypsexec library

Tags: python-3.x, powershell

Not able replace a word in txt file using powershell commands on remote machine using python pypsexec library

I have tried below code:

```
ip = '10.X.X'
username = 'administrator'
password = 'XXXXXX'
try:
    c = Client(ip, username, password, encrypt = 'False')
    c.connect()
    c.create_service()
    print ('service created for following "{}".......\n\n'.format(ip))
    callback = '''(Get-Content "C:\PROGRA~1\sample.txt")|ForEach-Object{ $_ -replace "# cluster.link.enabled=true", "cluster.link.enabled=true"}|Set-Content "C:\PROGRA~1\sample.txt"'''
    stdout, stderr, rc = c.run_executable("powershell.exe",arguments=callback, remote_log_path = "C:\PROGRA~1\opt.txt")
    stdout = str(stdout, 'utf-8')
    stderr = str(stderr, 'utf-8')
    if rc == 0:
        print ('Call back executed successfully :\nCallBackName :\n{}\nOutPut :\n{}\n\n'.format(callback,stdout))
    else:
        print ('Call back failed with error :\nCallBackName :\n{}\nOutPut :\n{}\n\n'.format(callback,stderr))
except Exception as e:
    print('Below exception occured while connecting with "{}"........\n'.format(ip))
    print(e)
    print()

finally:
    c.remove_service()
    c.disconnect()
    print('service removed for following "{}"'.format(ip))
```

i have a txt file on remote machine with following data :

# cluster.link.enabled=true

My expected results should be :
cluster.link.enabled=true

Comment: So what exactly happens / doesn't happen when you run your script? Please update your question directly with a clarification.

Comment: When I am executing below command on powershell command is working fine and replacing the matching word in file. But when I am executing through above python script word is not replacing and getting return code as 0. Command:  '''(Get-Content "C:\PROGRA~1\sample.txt")|ForEach-Object{ $_ -replace "# cluster.link.enabled=true", "cluster.link.enabled=true"}|Set-Content "C:\PROGRA~1\sample.txt"'''

Comment: Please update your question directly, so that (a) all information is in one place, (b) code can be formatted readably. Generally, try to provide an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or as close as you can get to one.

Answer (score 0):

The dot `.` in Regex is a special character meaning **any character**.
In PowerShell, `-replace` uses Regex, so you need to escape that dot.

```
$_ -replace "# cluster.link.enabled=true"
```

should be

```
$_ -replace [regex]::Escape('# cluster.link.enabled=true')
```